# Dark Color Appreared on checkbox on phone but ok when seen in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ngo_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <font.CustomFontTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/ngo_name"
        app:typeface="roboto_bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_ngo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_tint"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ngo_desc_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black_tint"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for checkbox in xml file, I am calling this file in inflator layout (if relevant) and it shows blue tick mark when checked.

When checkbox is viewed inside phone:
[image: Device]
When checkbox is viewed inside Android Studio:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/owrVq.png]

Answer (score 0):

Use buttonTint for the box: (API level 23)

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:buttonTint="@color/black_tint" />
```

For older APIs use :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:buttonTint="@color/black_tint" />
```

Comment: I have to use api level 17-21 can you tell me something in that context...?